# Rewriting to decoded URLs across entire site

Tags: htmlspecialchars-decode

We have an information reference site that uses a plugin called WPAutomatic to pull in a few feeds and automatically creates posts. Sometimes items in the feed come in with undecoded URLs which crap out with the "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer..." error.

An example link would be https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DwgO9qGYg1h8

After decoding UTF-8 it should read: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgO9qGYg1h8

How can I approach solving this issue? I need to rewrite the existing URLs to decoded URLS—hundreds of them—and also need to make sure the URLs from this feed are decoded in all new posts going forward.

Have tried looking for a plugin but no luck so far. Any ideas?

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: have you raised this issue with WPAutomatic? 3rd party plugin dev support questions are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: Thanks, @TomJNowell. I've requested a fix couple years ago but they ignored it. I'm not necessarily looking to modify the plugin, generally interested in how to run a filter or script that can modify old posts.  There are some 10 year old posts that could also get their URLs updated in a similar fashion that aren't from WPAutomatic.

Comment: Guess you could write a function that scrapes through all the URLs in the DB (for this plugin's records) and fixes them... ...then set it to run as a CRON job.  I'd record the value of when the CRON ran and then, after a manually triggered 'do all', I'd have it only run on records that are added after the last time it ran. Assuming that however this plugin records the URLs also includes a date/time they were added. Good luck.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks @TonyDjukic! This sounds like a reasonable approach, I will see if I can make this happen. Really appreciate the thought!